# Process terminating with default action of signal 11 [SIGSEGV]

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am building a C++ project in Eclipse. It uses SQLITE3 for database and libxml for reading specific data from a XML file. The code compiles fine and the executable is generated. However when I run the binary it terminates with this message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

When I run the Valgrind profiler to detect where the memory leak is I get this huge log file which I can make no sense of.

```
    ==4960== Invalid read of size 4
    ==4960==    at 0x41C6EB7: sqlite3SafetyCheckSickOrOk (sqlite3.c:22048)
    ==4960==    by 0x41EADCA: sqlite3_close (sqlite3.c:112926)
    ==4960==    by 0x804A551: Database::close() (CEMDAPnew.cpp:133)
    ==4960==    by 0x805D2F3: CDataCoordinator::ReadVehicleMakeData(std::string) (DataCoordinator.cpp:2709)
    ==4960==    by 0x80689D4: main (GauravWithoutMPI.cpp:36)
    ==4960==  Address 0x4dc1fd0 is 64 bytes inside a block of size 512 free'd
    ==4960==    at 0x402B06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
    ==4960==    by 0x41B520F: sqlite3MemFree (sqlite3.c:15252)
    ==4960==    by 0x41A2DF0: sqlite3_free (sqlite3.c:18986)
    ==4960==    by 0x41EB0B4: sqlite3_close (sqlite3.c:113040)
    ==4960==    by 0x804A551: Database::close() (CEMDAPnew.cpp:133)
    ==4960==    by 0x805D2F3: CDataCoordinator::ReadVehicleMakeData(std::string) (DataCoordinator.cpp:2709)
    ==4960==    by 0x80689D4: main (GauravWithoutMPI.cpp:36)
    ==4960== 
    ==4960== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==4960==    at 0x4532DD8: inflateReset2 (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==4960==    by 0x4532EC7: inflateInit2_ (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==4960==    by 0x512FE6B: ???
    ==4960== 
    ==4960== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==4960==    at 0x4532DD8: inflateReset2 (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==4960==    by 0x4532EC7: inflateInit2_ (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==4960==    by 0x5056E135: ???
    ==4960== 
    ==4960== Invalid read of size 4
    ==4960==    at 0x80BD81C: CMdcevMM::loadXmlString(_xmlNode*, _xmlDoc*, unsigned char*) (ModelModule.cpp:2849)
    ==4960==    by 0x810D73A: CSimCoordinator::LoadXmlString(char const*) (simCoordinator.cpp:8313)
    ==4960==    by 0x8068A4E: main (GauravWithoutMPI.cpp:45)
    ==4960==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
    ==4960== 
    ==4960== 
    ==4960== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
```

I need to make sense of this output. Can anyone help me make sense of this error and what is the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should start fixing `Invalid read` errors. They are the most likely reason of Segmentation fault, which has nothing to do with memory leaks.

The first `Invalid read` in Valgrind output means that `sqlite3SafetyCheckSickOrOk` call referred to some memory already freed previously. The exact call stack where it happened is printed below. This looks strange because it happened in `sqlite3_close` which than refers to freed memory. Probably this is sqlite bug.

The second `Invalid read` means referring to NULL pointer in `CMdcevMM::loadXmlString`. Check your code.

Comment: So I should start with all the `Invalid read`? I had been thinking up till now that Segmentation fault and memory leaks are one an the same! So the other messages are just errors that affect memory usage efficiency?

Comment: Yes, `Invalid read` are more critical errors. Other errors should also be fixed, but sometimes you can ignore them, this depends on exact error message. `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value` can be probably ignored because it originate in libz, not in your code.